# What are the conditions that allow killing animals out of self-defense?

Tags: animals, self-defense

Dear brothers and sisters

My question regards the type of animals that at first glance don't cause any fatal harm to a human being

So, I wondered for a while if it is allowed to kill mosquitoes who sting you to feed themselves with your blood. I often kill them and cite Surah Al-Ikhlas 3 times and then throw them away in the dustbin.

And I also wonder now if it is permissible to kill animals who bite you without any physical harm except for a scar. (E.g. non-venomous snakes, fire ants, non-venomous spiders, etc...)

Please show your source as you explain how you should deal with those type of animals.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

> It was narrated from Ibn Umar that he heard the Messenger of Allah (SAW) address the people from the minbar, saying: “Kill snakes.”
>
> ‘Abdullah ibn ‘Umar said: "After that, I would not leave any snake that
> I saw but I would kill it."
>
> Narrated by al-Bukhaari (3298) and Muslim (3233)

Sources:

https://sunnah.com/bukhari/59/106

Comment: I appreciate the hadith that is focused on the case of the snakes. Was there something mentioned about other type of animals, especially mosquitoes?